# check the text of labels in gridview and change its background color on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I tried to check get text on each cell in rowdatabound so that kinda didn't work for me as it gave blank record. Below is my design.On Rowdatabound get the label of each cell and check the values and change the background colour accordingly. I need to find row cell.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grv_taskfilter" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    style="margin-top: 0px" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px"  CellPadding="2"
    CellSpacing="1" Font-Size="XX-Small" GridLines="None" >
        <Columns>
            <%--<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Project ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProjectID" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>--%>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ProjectNamehead" Text='Project Name' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <a href="Task_description.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ProjectName")%>&flag=0" > <%# Eval("ProjectName") %></a>
                   <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="lbl_ProjectName" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>' 
                        PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Task_description.aspx?RowIndex=" & Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                       runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>                                   
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ProjectNoshead" Text='Project nos' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProjectNos" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectNos") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                                    
            </asp:TemplateField>                               

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_QuestionScripting" Text='Questionnaire Submission for sripting' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion_Scripting" Text='<%# Eval("Questionnaire_Submission_for_sripting") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                                   
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Programing" Text='Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send out' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrograming_questionnaire" Text='<%# Eval("Programing_of_questionnaire_and_or_ConJoint_Design_Email_Send_out") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                                   
            </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: add `OnRowdatabound` event code too

Comment: Use `(Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProjectID")`, but you need to check the the current row's type is `DataItem`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter row's type should be `DataRow`, not `DataItem`

Comment: @Shaharyar: yes of course :)

Comment: i have mentioned the rowdatabound code below this also doesnt work for me guys

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {

              for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
              {

                  Label lbl1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_Question_Scripting");//use e.rows.cell[]

                  if (lbl1.Text == "Not yet started")
                  {
                      e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Gray;
                  }

                  if (lbl1.Text == "In progress")
                  {
                      e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Orange;
                  }

                  if (lbl1.Text == "Alert")
                  {
                      e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                  }
                  if (lbl1.Text == "Missed deadline")
                  {
                      e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                      // e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
                  }
                  if (lbl1.Text == "Not Applicable")
                  {
                      e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                  }

          }
      }
```

when i do this it changes the entire row color like i tried with forecolor here every cell should have different colour depending on status

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row cell, try this

```
protected void grv_taskfilter_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow grv = (GridViewRow)e.Row;

            Label lbl1 = (Label)grv.FindControl("lblQuestion_Scripting");
            if (lbl1.Text == "Condition_Text")
            {
                TableCell rowCell = (TableCell)lbl1.Parent;
                rowCell.Style["background"] = "red";
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1:
You may consider this a hacky solution. The following code will assume that the number of columns is fixed, it will use a datatable as datasource, and css class for the cell background

1. Add a column for each of the existing columns that require the conditions. For example, if you have a "STATUS" column, you can add "STATUS_CSS" column.
2. Before binding the datasource, apply your conditions to the fields and set the CSS columns to their appropriate css class name
3. Bind your datasource then use the following RowDataBound

-

```
protected void grv_taskfilter_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow grv = (GridViewRow)e.Row;
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;//you'll need to cast to another object if you're not using datatable
            //No need to check the value of the label. It should have been handled in step 2 above

            grv.Cells[0].CssClass = drv["Status_CSS"].ToString();// Fixed colums: Assuming that cell 0 will always be for Status
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks seven21 this worked for me in case on one column but now i have around 18 columns with seven different condition so writing this code for each of them wil make code look cluttered is there any other way out.

Comment: @user2583182: see my EDIT 1

Comment: I NEED TO FIND EACH CONTROL LIKE LABEL FROM EACH CELLS. and then check condition for single control and change its background color